# Why dose current only take the path of zero resistance in a parallel circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, short-circuits

If a resistor in placed in parallel with a wire of zero resistance the current only flows though the path of zero resistance. What stops the the current from flowing thought the resistor?

Also how do we measure that current since by Ohm's law V/R = I, and if R = 0 then I is undefined.

If the wire has a non-zero resistance less than the resistor, then current will flow though both, however, more current will flow though the wire because it has a lower resistance for the same electric potential difference according to Ohm's Law (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrIY1UlogBg).

Comment: Ohms law does not apply for r=0, since it is the steady state solution given acceleration is zero, ( when the resistive force equals electric force), when r=0, there is no steady state. Hence the undefined current.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is 1 A flowing through the zero-resistance wire.

What then is the voltage across the wire? From Ohm's law we know the voltage across it is 0 V.

Since the other resistor is in parallel, the voltage across it is the same: Also 0 V.

Since this resistor has non-zero resistance, what is the current flowing through it with 0 V across it? Again you can use Ohm's law to find the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the current flowing across the resistor would be zero right? Because there would need to be an electric potential difference to produce and electric force in the wire.

Comment: Even in zero resistance wires, V≠0 as a general rule. This just means that zero potential is needed to maintain a constant current. Given I apply an initial PD, a current increases and reaches some fin value. When the PD is taken away, the current doesn't change  since there's zero resistance. An object will continue to move at a constant velocity in the absence of forces

Comment: Thanks for your comment can you explain why electric potential difference cannot equal zero in a circuit with zero resistance?

Comment: It can equal zero, given the current is constant. Which is only the case if there is no electric field present. A good way to understand why V=i*0=0 doesn't mean that the potential is always zero, is to understand the derivation of ohms law. Ohms law is derived as a steady state solution  where the motion of an electron is calculated given it experiences an electric force  , and a resistive force proportional to velocity. When the resistive force equals the electric force , the velocity of the electron  and therefore current is constant. --

Comment: This condition  means that V represents the potential difference needed to maintain a constant current. The presence of V=0, therefore means that in the absence of resistance, zero potential is needed to maintain the current, as there is no resistive force opposing its motion. That is NOT to say, that when resistance is zero , the current is constant!, our conclusions about the potential only hold, given we ASSUME the current is constant

Comment: Now that I've explained the confusion with the result from ohms law. A direct proof  is if E did equal  0 in the wire, it would violate the condition that the closed line integral of E = 0, as there is a potential drop inside a battery but zero across the wires, making a non zero line integral. Or more intuitively. " why would the presence of resistance, have any bearing on the electric field generated by a battery"

Comment: Zero resistance means free electrons. If I apply an electric field.on a free electron. It OBVIOUSLY experiences a non zero force  and hence a non zero emf.

Comment: @jensenpaull, in problems of this type we're typically asking for a steady state solution. Meaning one in which all time derivatives go to zero. So all this consideration of the inherent inductance of the wire (without naming it for some reason) is irrelevant.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks your answer, do you know the answer to this question which really is a complement to the other question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714356/another-electricity-controversy-following-veritasium It will probably help my understanding I think.

Comment: Then you start listening to what @jensenpaull is saying about dI/dt. Meaning, the current keeps increasing indefinitely until you realize something about your model is not accurate --- either your source can't provide enough charge to maintain the current, or your resistor isn't truly zero resistance. Or something catches fire.

Comment: @ThePhoton Sorry I'm not really sure. Imagine that you has a large electric potential difference across two parallel branch's in a circuit. One branch has zero electric resistance, and the other branch has a load such as resistor. Which path(s) will the current take and why?

Comment: I am  not talking about inductance. Just the inherent assumptions of ohms law to be valid. I think its an important distinction to be made, that when r=0, v≠ 0 in general. A diagram with a battery and a 0 resistance wire  wouldn't never have a constant current in it, but abstractions lead people to always say E=0, even though in reality that's ridiculous. The only way V=0 for r=0, is if there is no battery.

Comment: @jensenpaull when you said "If there was a non zero potential difference across a zero resistance wire, the current would be continually increasing.", what physical mechanism are you describing other than inductance?

Comment: Inductance is the opposition of the change in current due to the induced emf as a result of a changing magnetic  field. I am simply describing the force on a free electron due to the electric field of the battery ( although yes  the inductance contributes to the net force)

Answer (score 1):

> [...] What stops the the current from flowing thought the resistor?

Well, the resistance stops it. Every charge that reaches the junction will move in the direction of least resistance. They will slow down slightly if there is a small resistance, and will start queueing up. After a few charges have moved this way, further charges that arrive will feel that the high-resistance wire is more accessible and will move that way. They will also be slowed down and start queueing up, but faster since there is a higher resistance. And then further charges that arrive will again choose the low-resistance wire. And so on it continues.

In the case of absolutely zero resistance along one wire (which is an idealisation), there will never any slowing down and queueing up along this wire. So any new arriving charge will prefer this path. There will never be a reason to pick the higher-resistance path.

> Also how do we measure that current since by Ohm's law V/R = I, and if R = 0 then I is undefined.

Yes, we cannot directly use Ohm's law in the case of zero resistance since, mathematically, the result is undefined and the scenario impossible/illegal. Physically, we can consider what happens as the resistance reduces and approches lower and lower values until practically zero: while the resistance $R$ reduces, so does the voltage drop $V$. When very close to $R\to 0$, then you can divide the two very small values with each other and reach a value of $I$. The case of $R$ actually becoming zero would be the limiting case of this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just one question, what would happen if there was a non-zero electric potential difference across the resistor, and zero-resistance wire? Would the current still flow down the zero resistance path, why?

Comment: @GravityMan There will (in steady state) not be a non-zero voltage (electrical potential difference) across a zero-resistor. A non-zero voltage appears as a "pump" to push current through resistance - if there is no resistance, no voltage will appear.

Comment: If there was a non zero potential difference across a zero resistance wire, the current would be continually increasing. The presence of no resistance  does NOT imply there is zero voltage. This is only the case given we KNOW the current is constant

Comment: For the eq $$V=IR$$ to work. You must have 2 knowns  and 1 unknown. when "I" is known  and r decreases to infinitely small, then V decreases . Re arranging as $$ \frac{V}{R} = I$$ to solve for current we need a known value of V  and a known value of R,  in no way shape or form are you "dividing a small value of v  and a small value of r" as the small value of V you originally obtain  is derived under the assumption you KNOW "I". You couldn't even apply your logic to find the value of "I" , it's mathematically impossible and illogical.

Comment: You need to use $$\frac{V}{R} = I$$ using some known potential value, and then take the limit at r goes to zero. Which in return gives an infinite current. This os not a valid way to assess zero resistance wires since this "Steady state" solution would take an infinite amount of time to reach, and would.not yield physic results.