# Electricity Paradox

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, short-circuits

Imagine that you has a large electric potential difference across two parallel branch's in a circuit. One branch has zero electric resistance, and the other branch has a load such as resistor. Which path(s) will the current take and why?

Comment: I've deleted a comment based on the now edited question. How much current is required through a *"zero electric resistance"* branch to produce a non-zero voltage across that branch?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Thanks for you comment. You can't create a non-zero voltage across a zero electric resistance path because R = 0, when put into Ohm's law right?

Comment: That's correct in the context of ideal circuit theory.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Thanks for you comment. Sorry which path(s) will the current take?

Comment: Please add some additional details to your question. It will help the community members to answer your question properly.

Answer (score 1):

In a static situation, zero resistance implies no potential difference. The current keeps flowing through the branch without resistance even after the source for initiate the current is not more present.

If there is an AC source, both branches have inductance, so the current flowing in each one is a function of the respective impedance.